# How to suppress 'Single-Click' event In openlayers 3 while drawing on map

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am using openlayers 3.20.0. And below link will show you the small example.

[click-here.](https://jsfiddle.net/f0cjkksg/1/) (In the example see the console for logs)

I have a map object as

```
this.map = new ol.Map({
    layers : [ somelayer ],
    target : 'map',
    view : new ol.View({
        center : [ -11000000, 4600000 ],
        zoom : 4
    })
});
```

Here I have attached '**singleclick**' and '**dblclick**' on map.

And also I have draw interaction on map, as below

```
this.draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    features : features,
    type : "Point"
});
```

which is emits '**drawstart**' and '**drawend**' event.

But when we are drawing a point it will emit 'singleclick' event on map also. How can we prevent this from not emitting the 'singleclick' while drawing.

I know we can remove the 'singleclick' event listener while drawing, but I don't want to remove listener and add again.

Is there any other way of suppressing this event.

Comment: `event.stopPropagation();` use this.

Comment: I have tried with that one also, but not working.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to suppress, since nothing changes if `singleclick` is or not active. But I think you're looking for `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: When we are drawing I do not want the **singleclick** event to fire. I tried with the `event.stopPropagation()` also. But It will fire **drawstart**  then **drawend** and finally **singleclick** events.

Comment: It would also be nice to know why you want to prevent the event from occuring.  If that's because you have other tools active at the same time, you could instead deactivate them while you're drawing.

Comment: I am doing some important work when user clicks on feature (singleclick). But while drawing I don't want that one to fire.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I solved this with unByKey method. Every map.on method returns a unique key. You can use map.unByKey(singleclick_key) to stop single click event. You can initialize it after completing your drawing on more time.

So, you are looking for something like this:

```
var singleclick_key= map.on('singleclick', function(evt){
//statements
}
```

and you can remove this event by using the following command:

```
map.unByKey(singleclick_key);
```